# Downloading a text file from a website ignores new lines

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, httpwebresponse

I am trying to download a text file (changelog) from a website and write it in a component in C#.

I tried listbox, listview, textbox but I don't think it matters. The new lines get completely ignored and it displays straight in 1 line all the data.

I tried the following methods:

```
var web = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://somesite.com/changelog.txt");
web.Method = "GET";

using (var res = new StreamReader(web.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    textBox1.Text = res.ReadToEnd();
}
```

And

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string changelog = wc.DownloadString("http://somesite.com/changelog.txt");
    textBox1.Text = changelog;
}
```

Both of the methods returned 1 line of all the data. I need the new lines so I can use it in textBox for example and make it look properly. Right now it's very messy in 1 line and unreadable.

Sample changelog.txt content:

```
1.0.1.2
- Initial release

1.0.0.3
- Initial release

1.0.0.2
- Initial release
- Initial release
- Initial release

1.0.0.1
- Initial release
- Initial release
- Initial release

1.0.0.0
- Initial release
```

Fixed it by adding `.Replace("\n", "\r\n");` at the end of `textBox1.Text = res.ReadToEnd();`

`textBox1.Text = res.ReadToEnd().Replace("\n", "\r\n");`

Comment: Show a sample of `changelog.txt` content

Comment: Is it a Unix line end terminated file, by any chance?

Comment: is your textbox multiline ?

Comment: @RemusRusanu I'm not sure how to check that. All I know is that the file is hosted on a Linux server.

Comment: then according to your first code it's giving me a proper output

Comment: can you please add your output so we can see what you get

Comment: @PranavPatel But my `TextBox` control is multi-line as well and I'm not getting the same output. [Here is the control setting](https://gyazo.com/43a204c000d0678c276b645259f1307a)

Comment: @PranavPatel [this is what I get](https://gyazo.com/df38478332af8044b412248f648bc656)

Comment: @RemusRusanu Your post has inspired me to try something and it worked. I have fixed the issue. If you would like, feel free to post an answer. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by this way :

```
var web = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://somesite.com/changelog.txt");        
web.Method = "GET";    
using (var res = new StreamReader(web.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    string line="";
    while ((line=res.ReadLine())!=null)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(line+System.Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```